# MVC 6 - Can't recreate "wrap"-folder

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm working on a MVC 6 application which I added to the source control (TFS). VS2015 does not add the "wrap"-folder to the source control, which is good. But once another developer "get latest" the wrap folder is missing and VS2015 can't recreate the folder and the referenced projects in the solution can't be resolved.

If I manually add the "wrap"-folder to the source control, then every time I add a project, I need to manually add a folder in VS2015 and add the new project.json file.

What do others do?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. Seems the only way to force VS to re-create the wrap folder, is to remove and re-add the references in the Projects.json file :(

The wrap folder can also be created by running the "DNU wrap" command.
This is my workaround:

I added this to my .xproj project file:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Message Text="RuntimeToolingDirectory: '$(RuntimeToolingDirectory)'" Importance="high" />
    <Exec Command="AddReferences.cmd &quot;$(RuntimeToolingDirectory)&quot;"/>
</Target>
```

The AddReferences.cmd file in my project folder looks like this:

```
echo Checking if wrap folder already exists in solution root folder ...
if not exist ..\wrap goto do
echo wrap already exists...   skipping creation
goto end

:do
echo No wrap folder found. Creating ...
call %1\bin\dnu wrap ..\MyService\MyService.csproj

:end
```

So if wrap folder does not exist, it will be created using DNU.
You still need to manually update the cmd when you add or remove references, and it cannot handle an existing but incomplete wrap folder.

This way I don't need the wrap folder in source control.

Guess the solution could be improved by parsing the project file and look for references (project/file) so you don't need to manually add/remove in cmd file.

You could also choose to run DNU unconditionally to always have a valid wrap folder, but it will cost seconds on every build.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser! I'm currently doing another project, but I will be back on this next week, and i'll test it out!